# Don't understand how Java Scanner object is working in this example (hasNextInt, next...?)

Tags: java, while-loop

In my program I need to take an input from a user, but it must be an integer. If the user doesn't input an integer, I need the program to reprompt them to enter an integer, and keep doing so until they enter one. I found an example while loop code snippet online which works perfectly, but I am having problems understanding why and how it works, and I'd really like to understand better:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);      
int guess=0;             
System.out.println("Guess the number"); 

while (!reader.hasNextInt()) {      //I get that this is a "not have" boolean
    System.out.println("That's not a number. Please enter a valid number");
    reader.next();
}

guess= reader.nextInt();
System.out.println(guess);
```

My questions are:

1. Does the !hasNext condition in the while loop actually trigger the scanner object to ask the user for input and then check that input, or does it only check anything that has already been inputted?
2. Why is it necessary to have the reader.next(); line after the while loop's main statement and what is this doing exactly? I know it's necessary as the program doesn't work when I take it out. But is it prompting for input? If yes what happens to this input?
3. When guess= reader.nextInt(); runs, why doesn't it re-prompt the user for input at this point?

Sorry that these are probably really basic questions, I'm new to coding and Java and just can't get my head around what's happening internally in this particular example, though have no problem doing other basic stuff with the Scanner.

Comment: It takes longer to write a question on stackoverflow than to google [java Scanner hasNextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) and [java !operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Comment: Yet another "I'm new" excuse to prevent own research and own testing. You can _easily_ find out why you need `next()` when you remove it and test what happens then.

Comment: Sorry but I have actually spent a long time trying to work this out myself and have looked at lots of previous questions, this honestly was a last resort. As I said I knew that next() was necessary because I had experimented and removed it and it didn't work. I didn't understand WHY it was necessary.

Comment: There are even existing questions (and answers) for that .. [How to handle infinite loop caused by invalid input using Scanner](//stackoverflow.com/q/3572160)

Comment: I searched a lot of questions and did not find that particular one. I was looking to understand WHY the loop/Scanner acted as it did, and a lot of the questions/answers I found stopped at giving the correct code.

I probably seem incredibly dense to you, but I am not lying when I say that I spent time experimenting with the code and searching online to try to understand it, but didn't. The answer that someone gave me here was worded in such a way that I now DO understand it, which is surely a good thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not particularly intuitive, for sure, so don't feel bad for not getting it immediately.

It seems to me that the problem you're having with your understanding is that that methods such as `nextInt` *may or may not* prompt for user input, depending if anything is already in the Scanner.

---

Here's the sequence of events:

All your code executes until you hit `!reader.hasNextInt()`. There's no input so it "blocks" (waits) until there is some input from the user.

If the user enters 'A', that's not an integer so we enter the body of the while loop. We then print the error message.

Now, `hasNextInt` doesn't "consume" (process) the user input when it's checking whether or not it's an integer, so we still have that invalid user input of 'A' sitting in our scanner. We call `reader.next()` to effectively discard that value.

Now we're back to `!reader.hasNextInt()`. The scanner is empty once again, so we prompt for user input. If they enter another non-integer, that process will simply keep repeating.

Say this time we do have a valid user input - they've entered the number 2. This passes the check so our while loop ends and we continue along.

We've now got some input in our scanner, but we've not consumed it. We're sure it's an integer because of the while loop condition. We can now consume the input with `reader.nextInt()` and assign it to our variable.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I think something that was also confusing me is that the scanner will "take"/"store" (whatever the correct terminonlogy is) a non-integer input at the !hasNextInt bit,but your answer really helps clear that confusion up for me. Thank you also for not making me feel stupid.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Remember to upvote any answers you find useful, and to accept the best one.

Comment: My upvotes are recorded but not displayed as I am too new a user, I think the same goes for accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. `hasNextInt()` only checks whether the next input is an integer. It won't consume any input at all. The `!` is just negate theu outcome of this function.
2. As `hasNextInt()` won't consume, then we need to use `next()` to consumeo the user input to let `hasNextInt()` to check with user's next input value. As you won't need it at all, then no need to assign it to any variables.
3. `Scanner` won't display the prompt at all. The prompt is printed by `System.out.println()`.

   For the line `nextInt()`, it is used to consume the next user input. Since `hasNextInt()` must be true when it execute this line, there must be one integer input waiting for consumption, so this method can return immediately with that user input.

Comment: The `!`-Operator is missing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that the print statement is the thing that displays the message asking for input, but is it really the thing that triggers letting the user actually input something? I thought that must be happening via one of the Scanner lines, but the problem is I can't work out if its letting the user input something at hasNextInt() in the while condition, why it isn't also asking for another input at guess=reader.nextInt(); when it exits the loop.

I think I am missing something fundamental in understanding the Scanner here!

Comment: `hasNextInt()` needs to have some input to check.  It will try to find an integer in any unconsumed input that the user has already typed, but if necessary it will wait for the user to type another line.

Answer (score -2):

```
 Try it :)
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int option;
        if(args!=null&&args.length>0){
        option = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("Enter:\n 1 to run x \n 2 to run y \n");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         option = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                xx
                break;
            case 2:
                yy
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the question? Have you tried to understand it? Why do you think "Don't understand how Java Scanner object is working in this example" means "Give me some other code smell filled code with no relation to my example"?

Comment: only want suggest, this code is basic and u can debug to know scanner int :)

Comment: This suggested code can't be less helpful as it is. It doesn't even contain any of OPs three questions to provide a debugging help. It neither helps him/her to understand the `while (!reader.hasNextInt())` loop or why `reader.next()` exists in that code.